# What is native memory? How to deallocate it?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, profiler

Android Profiler in android studio 3 shows Native Memory Allocation as on picture[image: pic]

In my app it grows and never free even after activity is destroyed. Why?

Comment: You can check this more information [Native Memory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3KLZ/com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.doc/topics/memory_overview.html)

Comment: Always call garbage collector to free up the memory in your destroy method `System.runFinalization();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    System.gc();`

Comment: Same is happening in my device native memory continuously grows and never gets destroyed. Are you able to find any solution?

Comment: @Chitrang As documentation says "Native: Memory from objects allocated from C or C++ code.

Even if you're not using C++ in your app, you might see some native memory used here because the Android framework uses native memory to handle various tasks on your behalf, such as when handling image assets and other graphics—even though the code you've written is in Java or Kotlin" 
So I had to find everything that is not used and close it. This video also helped me 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_caITSjk1k

Comment: Thanks for the response and I've gone through the video but still, I'm not able to find the solution. Only question, is there any solution to destroy native memory from JAVA, C or C++ code in android? If yes then how? Because native memory is increasing by 2MB per fragment scroll.

Comment: @Chitrang, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Keselme no friend I still haven't found any clue for this, sorry.